# How to re-establish connection to paired bluetooth LE device on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy

I successfully paired with my BLE device through windows UI, registered notifications and obtained them. And I have two questions:

1. How can I reconnect to advertising device again if connection was terminated?
2. How to detect disconnection and reconnection of BLE device? With the help of PnP?

I asked about it on windows msdn but without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved this issue. To be registered on notifications is not enough, you need read or write value in characteristics and Windows stack will start reconnection session automatically.